# doubts regarding Google Merchant account required to publish games having in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay, merchant-account

this is my first question here.
so the thing is

- I have developed an android game having In App Purchase feature
- I have used my friend's debit card to pay $25 to get a developer
  account on  google play.

My doubts are

- How do I get money of In App Purchased products?(I know that Google merchant account is required for that. But I want to know more in detail)
- Can we transfer that money to our bank accounts?
- If 'Yes' then can I link my own bank account to google merchant account or it will be transferred to the account of my friend whose debit card I have used to pay $25 ?

sorry if my questions seems to be confusing. I am new to all this and didn't get any solution from google.

Please help me guys. Thank you!

Comment: how is this question related to SO?

Comment: sorry Tod, I know this question is not related to programming or topics discuss on SO. BUT I have spent so many unsatisfied days to clear my doubts and as a last option I posted this question. Please help me out if u know some information

Comment: how about looking for the right forum to ask this?

Comment: yeah I tried there too. I have only last doubt which I mentioned above.

Comment: @kishorB - Did u find answer for this? If yes pls reply me.. I am also looking for that..

Comment: @Balaji , after i setting up Google merchant account I fount that there is a payment method option under which we can link our own bank account. And those who are worrying about website requirement for setting up Google merchant account Note that, i used url of my blog instead of any website. It worked. :)

Comment: @kishorB - yes. we can add our own bank account. If we added that, is the amount in google wallet automatically transferred to our bank account or we have to do it manually?

Comment: @Balaji, I have not tried that yet. I guess that is manual. I will let you know once my game goes online.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Google Merchant Account, there is a section called **Payment settings**.

Here you can set **Payment schedule** and **Payment method**.

> **Payment schedule:** The payment schedule is not changeable, but you can
>   apply a self-hold to prevent payout. Please note that changes to the
>   self-hold must be made before the 21st of the month to affect the
>   current month’s payment cycle.
>
> **Payment method:** This section allows you to select one of the payment methods available to you based on the country of your business address.

[image]

[image]